# str_replace and gsub in loops in R

Tags: gsub

I'm trying to remove single and double quotes plus forward and back slashes while looping through a data frame in R with one variable containing a series of lines of text.

str_replace_all works fine inside my loop to remove single and double quotes, but neither str_replace_all nor gsub works inside the loop.  They do, however, work fine when tested outside my loop.

Here's a toy data frame and the code I have tried.

```
# Demo Data Frame
dirtydat <- data.frame(V1 = c(
      "case01",
      "comment1: (s11) Positive "reinforcement"", 
      "comment2: (s44) Understanding this is 'crucial'",
      "comment3: (s10) This 'seems' /irrelevant/",
      "comment4: (s12) This is \narrow\ mindedness.",
      "datetime: 2018-11-29 02:27:16"))

# This is intended to remove single and double quotes plus forward and back slashes.
for(i in 1:nrow(dirtydat)) {
   str_replace_all(dirtydat[i,1], "\'", "")     # works inside the loop for single quote
   str_replace_all(dirtydat[i,1], "\"", "")     # works inside the loop for double quote
   #
   gsub("/", "", dirtydat[i,1])                 # works outside the loop, but not inside
   gsub("\\\\", "", dirtydat[i,1])              # works outside the loop, but not inside
   # Alternative approach to gsub()
   str_replace_all(dirtydat[i,1],  "/",  "")    # works outside the loop, but not inside  
   str_replace_all(dirtydat[i,1],  "\\\\",  "") # works outside the loop, but not inside
   #
   cat(dirtydat[i,1],"\n\n")                    # print each line i to see results
   }
```

I have also tried surroundinding the dirtydat[i,1] elements in the loop with eval(), but that had no effect.

I would appreciate advice on how to make str_replace_all() and/or gsub() work inside loops or any more efficient approaches I could use in R.  Thanks.

Comment: `cat(dirtydat$V1 <- gsub("[\"'\\\\/]+", "", dirtydat$V1))` removes all forward slashes, backslashes, single and double quotes. What you see in `"\narrow"` is not a backslash, it is an LF char defined with a string escape sequence `"\n"`, a newline char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
cat(dirtydat$V1 <- gsub("[\"'\\\\/]+", "", dirtydat$V1))
```

The `["'\\/]+` regex matches one or more occurrences of `"`, `'`, `\` and `/`. The backslash is doubled since this is a special regex metacharacter.